# Outlook 2010 VBA code to show alias of recipient

Tags: vba, email, outlook, alias

My company assigns each employee an ID which is stored as their 'alias' in Outlook. We use this ID often, and I am looking for an easy way to see it.
Right now I enter the recipient name in a new email, double click the name, click on more options, then Outlook properties. I am looking for a macro that where I would enter the recipient name in a new email, and then run the macro which would just pop up the recipient's alias as a message box  (ideally copy it to the clipboard). I have tried (and failed) to write this on my own.

The code I have so far is below. However, this code gives /o=corpexchange/ou=exchange administrative group.....

I am trying to get it to return the alias

```
 Sub ReadRecpDetail2()



Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem

Dim myRecipient As Outlook.recipient

 Dim recipient As Outlook.recipient


Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

Set myItem = myOlApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem


For Each recipient In myItem.Recipients
  recipient.Resolve
  MsgBox recipient.AddressEntry

Next recipient
    End Sub
```

**To Recreate:**

1. Open new outlook email
2. Enter email address and resolve
3. Run macro

Comment: How exactly is that alias stored? Do you do that programmatically (what is your code?) or through the Outlook UI?

Comment: The alias is stored in the global contact info, alongside the first and last name, etc.

Comment: Stored how? Who stores it? Exchange or your code? In the former case, do you just mean the NT account name?

Comment: The alias is stored in the GAL. I can access it via outlook properties when double clicking on recipient. I am trying to create a shortcut to see the alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all your help I was able to solve this by capturing recipient address entry, adding it as a new item, showing alias, then deleting the recipient:

```
Sub ReadRecpDetail()
Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myItem As Outlook.mailItem
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.recipient
Dim recipient As Outlook.recipient
Dim SMTPaddress As String
Dim entry As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim entrystring As String
Dim Copytoclipboard As New DataObject

Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set recipient = myItem.Recipients.Item(1)
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add(recipient.AddressEntry)

myRecipient.Resolve
entrystring = myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias
MsgBox (entrystring)
Copytoclipboard.SetText entrystring
Copytoclipboard.PutInClipboard
myRecipient.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following methods:

1. Use the [CreateRecipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866418(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class to create a Recipient object.
2. Call the [Resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862796(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Recipient class to resolve a Recipient object against the Address Book.
3. Get the [AddressEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863677(v=office.15).aspx) property value, returns the AddressEntry object corresponding to the resolved recipient.
4. Call the [GetExchangeUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869721(v=office.15).aspx) method of the AddressEntry class, it returns an ExchangeUser object that represents the AddressEntry if the AddressEntry belongs to an Exchange AddressList object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user.
5. The [Alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869719(v=office.15).aspx) property of the ExchangeUser class returns a String representing the alias for the ExchangeUser.

You may also find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks Eugene - I tried that but am having a hard time retrieving the current recipient from the open email i am writing(rather than the macro adding a recipient and then showing the details). Any chance you can post the code?

Comment: I tried to use the code on this [Site](http://www.electronmedia.in/wp/reading-outlook-recipient-details-jobtitle-alias-address-etc-through-vba/) but couldn't get it to work

Comment: I think I am almost there but still getting error - please see edited original question with current code

Comment: on the msgbox line I get the error that the object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Check if myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser returns null. That would mean you have a non-Exchange recipient. You might also want to check if myRecipient.Resolve returns true before you do anything with that recipient.

Comment: Resolve=True...I made a few changes and think I am closer, but I am not getting the output I want - please see original question above

Comment: And what is the latest issue? How does "not getting the output I want" manifest itself?

Comment: This code gives "/o=corpexchange/ou=exchange administrative group....."

I am trying to get it to return the alias - maybe modifying so to use the code: `msgbox(myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias)`

Comment: See [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I needed to print out all the user names of the recipients in an email so I could export them to another application. I based my solution off of your answer which is below in case it helps anyone else.

```
Sub PrintRecipientAliases()

    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim recipient As Outlook.recipient

    Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set myItem = myOlApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    For Each recipient In myItem.Recipients
        With recipient
            Debug.Print recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```